# How to iterate and parse JSON data in Node/Jade/Express views?

Tags: json, node.js, express, pug

I am very new to Node and still in the beginning stages of understanding its use and power. I apologize if this question comes across as very simple or naive - I did due research before asking.

In my express js application, I sent a GET request to a remote API and properly received the appropriate JSON data in return. I then passed it to my views (Jade) and currently have the ability the print the JSON in string form. That all works properly.

The JSON data I have is a group of people/members of a club with associated fields. I want to "grab" all the people and display their names and related information in a nicely organized table.

So my question is, **what is the best way to parse the JSON data so I can access the names and related information in the view**?

My request looks like this, where data is the JSON being sent to the view:

```
res.render('standings.jade', { locals: {
          data: body,
          title: 'Team Member Information'
        }
});
```

And my very simple view looks like:

```
h2= title
p= data
```

I've tried fooling around with data.members, data.[members], data.["members"], data[members], etc. to no avail. Surely it is something stupid that I am missing? I am interested in the members listing and the returned JSON looks like this:

```
{
"club":
{"id":1,"name":"This is a team name"},
"members":
[{"id":2,"name":"Test Name"},{"id":3,"name":"Another Name"},{"id":4,"name":"More Names"},{"id":5,"name":"Cool Person"}]
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle JSON data, use the `express.bodyParser()` middleware. That will make a `req.body` object available to you in your route callback. In the route handler function, pass `req.body` as part of the view's locals to make that data available to the view.

```
app.post("/some/path", express.bodyParser(), function (req, res) {
    res.render("standings.jade", {
        locals: {data: req.body, title: "Team Member Information"}
    });
});
```

In your view, you will be able to access `data.members` to get the team members.

```
each member in data.members
    p= member.name
```