# how can i render jade file

Tags: javascript, node.js

how can i render jade file and send data as json with socket.io

> render with express

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

i want something like this

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on("message", function(data) {
        //some think like this
        var a = render('index', { title: 'Express' });
        socket.emit({html:a,more_data:ffffffff});
    });
});
```

so i render it and add it in object for bass some data with it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570068/how-to-iterate-and-parse-json-data-in-node-jade-express-views

Comment: If you're looking to render Jade via Socket.IO then you're probably **doing it wrong**. Socket.IO is only meant for exchanging messages or simple (serializable) data. What you probably should be doing is writing client-side Javascript to receive and **update** the data into existing HTML via DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Please note: *This is an answer to your main question regarding Jade rendering. What you do with `socket.io` is up to you, but of course, you should consider sending only small packets of data back to the browser and do the rendering by client side templates instead.*

However, yes, you can manually render with [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/api/) in Node.js without the need of the Express framework. Please see [Jade API](http://jade-lang.com/api/) documentation for all the methods and options you can use.

Try this in your app.js:

```
var jade = require('jade');
var renderFunc = jade.compileFile('./views/layout.jade');
var html = renderFunc({ title: 'Express' });
console.log(html);
```